# Call different function in a reusable class in Swift

Tags: swift, function, class

I created a custom text field and call a function every time the user type on it, the problem is how can I know what function was going to call.

Here is my code for custom UITextField that call a function every type.

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(
            withTarget: self,
            selector: #selector(callFunction),
            object: textField)
        self.perform(
            #selector(callFunction),
            with: textField,
            afterDelay: 0.5)
        return true
    }
    @objc func callFunction(textField: UITextField) {
         functionToBeCall()
    }
}
```

As you can see in my code, I need that `functionToBeCall()` to be change in every class I use it, and that class was reusable so I can't set a static method in it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You could have a delegate protocol for your custom class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use delegation:

```
protocol CustomTextFieldDelegate: class {
    func customTextFieldDidChange(_ customTextField: CustomTextField)
}

class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
    weak var customDelegate: CustomTextFieldDelegate?

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(
            withTarget: self,
            selector: #selector(callFunction),
            object: textField)
        self.perform(
            #selector(callFunction),
            with: textField,
            afterDelay: 0.5)
        return true
    }

    @objc func callFunction(textField: UITextField) {
        customDelegate?.customTextFieldDidChange(self)
    }
}
```

Any class that uses a `CustomTextField` should adopt the `CustomTextFieldDelegate` protocol, implement the callback function, and set itself as the `customDelegate` on the `CustomTextField`.

---

**Example Usage:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomTextFieldDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let customTextField = CustomTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50))
        view.addSubview(customTextField)
        customTextField.customDelegate = self
    }
    
    func customTextFieldDidChange(_ customTextField: CustomTextField) {
        print("custom field was changed")
    }
    
}
```